# Is there a way to assign value to object using mocks

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I have a method that:

1. Accepts string as a parameter.
2. Creates object using that string.
3. Passes that object into another method.
4. That second method then changes a property on that object.
5. Then the original method checks if that property was changed, and throws an exception if it wasn't.

Code below. This method **cannot** be modified.

```
internal sealed class CreateUserCommandHandler
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public CreateUserCommandHandler(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public async Task Handle(string firstName)
    {
        var user = new User(firstName);

        await _userRepository.CreateUser(user);

        if (user.Id == null)
            throw new Exception("User Id is null after creation.");
    }
}
```

I want to test this method with unit tests. I don't know how to set up a user repository mock so that it would assign id property.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GivenCorrectCommand_WhenHandlerIsExecuted_ThenEntityShouldContainId()
{
    // Arrange;
    var firstName = "FirstName";
    var commandHandler = new CreateUserCommandHandler(_userRepositoryMock.Object);

    // Act
    // This throws an exception because of the user.Id property is equal to null
    var result = await commandHandler.Handle(firstName);

    // Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNullOrWhiteSpace();
}
```

I am using .NET 7, xUnit, Moq and FluentAssertions, I would prefer not to introduce new library if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can put some logic into `userRepositoryMock` like this

```cs
_userRepositoryMock
  .Setup(x => x.CreateUser(It.IsAny<User>()))
  .Callback((User u) => u.Id = 123);
```